# Blender keeps deleting my sculpt when I save

Tags: sculpting, saving

Im working on a sculpt and Blender keeps deleted the progress ive made when i try to save the file or if I do anything outside of sculpting the object at hand.

Ive attached images of before and after, does anyone know whats causing this and how to fix it?

[image]

[image]

Comment: Can you attach your .blend file to your question for us to have a look at. https://blend-exchange.com/

Comment: @Psyonic https://wetransfer.com/downloads/b2a89151d815fdb6d8a3141c8c3a5be920221210010033/6ff082967673b1c4e18d25c011fceec120221210010144/2a68b8 heres a wetransfer link. i tried deleting the multires modifier and re-adding it and that seemed to have worked but I dont think thats a good fix

Comment: That link has expired